# How would I print the next line after a matching pattern and then also stop when the matching pattern occurs once again using awk?

Tags: awk

I have a SQL file in the following format:

```
-- 1. Create a view 'c_summary' summarizing campaign contributions,
-- with four attributes: cand_name, contbr_name, amount, and zip. 

create view c_summary as
  select candidate.name as cand_name, contributor.name as contbr_name, amount, zip
    from candidate inner join contributor inner join contribution
      on candidate.cand_id = contribution.cand_id and
         contributor.contbr_id = contribution.contbr_id;

-- 2. For each of the occupations "STUDENT", "TEACHER", and "LAWYER",
-- show the occupation, and average size (in dollars) of contribution
-- from contributors with that occupation.

select occupation, round(avg(amount))
  from contributor natural join contribution
  where occupation in ("STUDENT", "TEACHER", "LAWYER")
  group by occupation;
```

I am trying to print out the lines that contain the query only when a question number is provided as a number to the `PROB` variable, and then to stop once another question is reached.

**For instance, I want the output to be like this for the second question:**

```
$ awk -f get_query.awk -v PROB=2 queries.sql
select occupation, round(avg(amount))
 from contributor natural join contribution
 where occupation in ("STUDENT", "TEACHER", "LAWYER")
 group by occupation;
```

**Or, the output to be like this for the 1st question:**

```
$ awk -f get_query.awk -v PROB=1 queries.sql
create view c_summary as
  select candidate.name as cand_name, contributor.name as contbr_name, amount, zip
    from candidate inner join contributor inner join contribution
      on candidate.cand_id = contribution.cand_id and
         contributor.contbr_id = contribution.contbr_id;
```

I tried the following, but the output I am getting is not what I want to get:

```
/^--/{
    RS="-- "
    getline
}
$0 ~ PROB{
    print $0
}
```

How would I modify my `awk` script to get my desired output?

Comment: Please post the expected output in code tags in your post too.

Comment: The expected output is provided in the question. I want it to output the query for each question. So, for the first problem I would do: `$ awk -f get_query.awk -v PROB=1 queries.sql` to get the SQL query only.

Comment: So it means you don't want lines which are starting with `-` etc?

Comment: Yes, I am trying to get only the lines that do not start with `--` for the specific problem number given to `PROB` in the awk statement.

Comment: Kindly check my answer and let me know if that helps you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***EDIT:*** Adding code for removing the control M characters too now in my previous code as OP has control M characters in OP's Input_file.

```
awk -v PROB=1 '{gsub(/\r/,"")} /^-/{next} !/^ +/&&!/^$/{count++}  count==PROB && NF' Input_file
```

---

Could you please try following and let me know if this helps you.

```
awk -v PROB=2 '/^-/{next} !/^ +/&&!/^$/{count++}  count==PROB && NF'  Input_file
```

In case you give `PROB=1` then following will be the output.

```
awk -v PROB=1 '/^-/{next} !/^ +/&&!/^$/{count++}  count==PROB && NF' Input_file
```

***Explanation:***

```
awk -v PROB=2 '                  ##Creating a variable named PROB whose value is 2 here.
/^-/             {  next     }   ##Checking if a line starts from dash then using next it will skip all further statements.
!/^ +/ && !/^$/  {  count++  }   ##Checking if a line not starts from space and is NOT a NULL line then increase the value of variable named count to 1.
count==PROB && NF                ##Checking condition here if variable count value is equal to variable PROB and line is NOT an empty line then print it.
' Input_file                     ##Mentioning the Input_file name here.
```

Comment: Removing output from above code now and only keeping codes and explanation in it.

Comment: When I try running this on a machine with AWK version 3.1.7 I don't get the output I want. Is it possible to make it compatible with that version?

Comment: @Grey, even my version is too `GNU Awk 3.1.7` and it working fine for me.

Comment: That's really weird. When I try to run it I get a blank line as the output.

Comment: @Grey, check also `cat -v Input_file` if you are seeing any control M characters in it? If yes then do let me know on same.

Comment: @Grey, Cool, please check my EDIT solution and let me know if that helps you?

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk -v RS= -v p=2 '(NR/2)==p' file
select occupation, round(avg(amount))
  from contributor natural join contribution
  where occupation in ("STUDENT", "TEACHER", "LAWYER")
  group by occupation;

$ awk -v RS= -v p=1 '(NR/2)==p' file
create view c_summary as
  select candidate.name as cand_name, contributor.name as contbr_name, amount, zip
    from candidate inner join contributor inner join contribution
      on candidate.cand_id = contribution.cand_id and
         contributor.contbr_id = contribution.contbr_id;
```